# With JAXB is it possible to generate a supertype?

Tags: java, jaxb

This this possible?

so if I have the jaxb classes

```
package com.example.client.jaxb.beans
AccountInfo.java
Contact.java
```

could I generate

```
package com.example.client.jaxb.beans
IApplicationBeans.java
AccountInfo.java implements IApplicationBeans
Contact.java implements IApplicationBeans
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The jaxb compiler wants to stay as "bean like" as possible. Since beans are pojos, having them in an inheritance structure doesn't make much sense.